# Python problema con unidades decenas centenas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código para intentar responder a esto a partir de un numero entero, diseñar un programa que cuente la cantidad de dígitos que posee y a partir de esto diga si pertenece a alguna de estas denominaciones:

```
numero = int (input ('Ingresa el valor de numero: '))
centenas=(numero%1000-numero%100)//100
decenas=(numero%100-numero%10)//10
milésima=(numero%100-numero%1000)//1000
decena_de_mil=(numero%1000-numero%10000)//10000
centena_de_mil=(numero%1000-numero%100000)//100000
unidades=numero%10
print ('Valor de centenas: ' + repr (centenas))
print ('Valor de decenas: ' + repr (decenas))
print ('Valor de milésima: ' + repr (milésima))
print ('Valor de decena_de_mil: ' + repr (decena_de_mil))
print ('centena_de_mil: ' + repr (centena_de_mil))
print ('cantidad de dígitos: ' + repr (unidades))
```

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta por favor, saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Cuál es tu pregunta? Tienes un enunciado y un código pero no sabemos cuál es tu pregunta. Lo otro: las etiquetas no son para hacer ruido sino para guiar la respuesta y para que lo sque más saben de un tema vean tu pregunta. Asumo que tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver con programación móvil, reactiva, asíncrona o bajo nivel. Ya viste que se puede editar la pregunta todas las veces que haga falta para mejorarla. Intenta de nuevo

Comment: Saludos, gracias por su observación, editada

Comment: Perfecto, vemos el código. Sin indentar y no va a correr ni se va a replicar lo que sea que ves porque suponer cómo está indentado hará que quede diferente al tuyo. E igual, seguimos igual: ¿Cuál. Es. Tu Pregunta? Si la pregunta es "está bien este código?", la respuesta la tienes tú mismo. Córrelo y prueba. Si está mal, dinos qué debe salir, qué te sale, etc. No somos un servicio de code review ;)

Comment: No he logrado lo de las  denominaciones (Unidad, decena, centena...)

Comment: he intentado de nuevo, pero no me toma la cantidad de datos y lo de las unidades es errado

Comment: De nuevo, revisa [ask]. Pon en el título _cuál es realmente la pregunta_. Por cierto, _Python_ es programación de **alto** nivel. La etiqueta de la pregunta debe ser el lenguaje en cuestión.

Answer (score 2):

vale, tu problema es bastante sencillo y te enseñaré cómo se hace.

Antes de proceder con el código, debes notar que el nombre `milésimas` se utiliza para nombrar los decimales del orden de `10^(-3)`, es decir `6132.23914` tiene `9` milésimas

este es el código:

```
numero = input('Ingresa el valor de numero: ')

denominaciones= [
    'unidades', 
    'decenas',
    'centenas',
    'unidades de millar',
    'decenas de miles',
    'centenas de miles'
]
for denominacion, digito in zip(denominaciones, numero[::-1]):
    print(f'Cantidad de {denominacion}:\t {digito}')

print (f'cantidad de dígitos: {len(numero)}')
```

(Puedes hacer el siguiente cambio con el mismo comportamiento por si no conocias la funcion `zip`)

```
for indice in range(len(numero)):
    print(f'Cantidad de {denominaciones[indice]}:\t {numero[::-1][indice]}')
```

este es mi output:

```
> python digitos-de-un-numero.py
Ingresa el valor de numero: 789231
Cantidad de unidades:    1
Cantidad de decenas:     3
Cantidad de centenas:    2
Cantidad de unidades de millar:  9
Cantidad de decenas de miles:    8
Cantidad de centenas de miles:   7
cantidad de dígitos: 6
```

otra prueba

```
> python digitos-de-un-numero.py
Ingresa el valor de numero: 738
Cantidad de unidades:    8
Cantidad de decenas:     3
Cantidad de centenas:    7
cantidad de dígitos: 3
```

**¿Cómo funciona?**: Al leer la variable con `input` obtendrás un string, y eso es lo que se aprovecha pues los strings son fáciles de agregarlos a los `print`. Creamos una lista con los nombres de los digitos (el programa solo es compatible con numeros de hasta 6 digitos, para agregar compatibilidad a mayor cantidad de digitos hay que agregar a la lista `denominaciones` los otros nombres que quieran ser soportados). Luego, recorremos los digitos y los nombres de manera que corresponda el digito con su denominacion. Como hemos puesto las denominaciones empezando por las unidades (leerias el numero desde la derecha) debemos invertir `numero` y esto lo logramos con `[::-1]`. Esta sentencia le dice a cualquier lista o string que devuelva la lista pero en reversa. Por ejemplo `'oso baboso'[::-1]` da como resultado `osobab oso`, mientras que `hola[::-1]` retorna `aloh`.

Nota:

Yo no busco reputación asi que porfavor no voten positivamente esta pregunta (si gustas vótala negativamente, a mi me da igual)

Comment: En este caso, el OP demuestra que se esforzó. Así que considero que merece una respuesta con explicación como la tuya! Igual más que perder reputación debería de preocuparte que te bloqueen la cuenta de responder.

Comment: @DanteS. hola, que es "la cuenta de responder"? Ya veo que borraron el comentario de "en este sitio no hacemos la tarea a nadie" asi que debo actualizar mi texto. Seria bueno que SO notifique en las ediciones para poder actualizar los textos que uno hace

Comment: Me refiero a que si, por ejemplo, recibes muchos votos negativos te pueden bloquear la cuenta de tal manera que puedas seguir publicando preguntas pero no respondiendolas. Aquí encontrarás más información: [¿Por qué ya no se aceptan respuestas desde mi cuenta?](/help/answer-bans)

Comment: Por cierto, sobre lo de que SO debería notificar las ediciones, esa es una propuesta que podrías hacer en [meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) ya que sería un cambio para todo Stack Exchange. Estoy de acuerdo con vos en ese sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Esto, más que programación es algoritmia. Como lo estás planteando está hecho de forma estática, y la programación debe ser dinámica, esto es: adaptarse a cualquier situación.
Supongamos que tenemos un número de ejemplo: **325**, entonces:

```py
>>> n = 325
>>> # ## Ciclo 1 ##
>>> n % 10
5 # <-- Unidades
>>> n = n // 10 # Ahora n es 32
>>> # ## Ciclo 2 ##
>>> n % 10
2 # <-- Decenas
>>> n //= 10 # Ahora n es 3
>>> # ## Ciclo 3 ##
>>> n % 10
3 # <-- Centenas
>>> n //= 10 # Ahora n es 0
>>> n
0 # <-- Fin del ciclo
```

Se puede observar, además, que la cantidad de dígitos es igual a la cantidad de ciclos, entonces se puede escribir un código mucho más dinámico usando ese algoritmo, por ejemplo:

```
numero = int (input ('Ingresa el valor de numero: '))

units = ['unidades', 'decenas', 'centenas', 'unidades miles', 'decenas miles', 
'centenas miles', 'unidades millones', 'decenas millones', '...puedes_agregar_mas']
i = 0 # <-- para contar los digitos
while numero > 0:
    print(f'Valor de {units[i]}: {numero % 10}')
    numero //= 10
    i += 1

print('La cantidad de digitos es:', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

un poco tarde pero espero que esto pueda ayudarte.

```
num=int(input("Ingrese un numero: "))
print("numero:",num)
if num<10:
  print("unidad")
elif num>=10 and num<99:
  print("decena")
elif num>=100 and num<=999:
  print("centena")
elif num>=1000 and num<=9999:
  print("milesima")
elif num>=10000 and num<=99999:
  print("decena de mil")
elif num>=100000:
  print("centena de mil")
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente cómo funciona este código, y cómo responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.